# LogLog plot in MATLAB is not creating a plot

Tags: matlab, graphing

I am trying to create a loglog plot of my function RMSE shown in the code below but whenever I run it, it just shows a blank graph any way I can fix this? Also my t is outputting the correct numbers when I display them.

```
for n = 1:10
    x = rand(1,n*2);
    y = rand(1,n*2);
    t = RMSE(x,y);
    loglog(t);
end

function [RMSE] = RMSE(x,y)
    Mx = mean(x);
    My = mean(y);
    RMSE = sqrt((Mx - .05)^2 + (My - .05)^2);
end
```

Comment: because `t` is just a single number each time. Store all `t(n)` in an array, then plot it

Comment: How would I store t(n) in an array? Would I do that inside the for loop?

Comment: `t(n) = RMSE(x,y)`, and move the `loglog` call to after the loop. Extra points for pre-allocating the array `t` before the loop: `t = zeros(1,n)`.